# Cleaning up a nasty looking loop

Tags: java

I have a working bloc of code that is a fairly ugly set of for, if and else's. I'm looking to clean it up, but I'm seeking advice on how to do so.

```
public String getContents() {
    if (Blanks.size() > madLibsContent.size()) {
        for(int i = 0; i <= Blanks.size() - 1; i++) {
            if (i == 0)
                contents += Blanks.get(i).getBlankValue() + " " + madLibsContent.get(i) + " ";
            else if (i == Blanks.size() - 1)
                contents += Blanks.get(i).getBlankValue();
            else 
                contents += Blanks.get(i).getBlankValue() + " " + madLibsContent.get(i) + " "; 
        }
    } else if (Blanks.size() < madLibsContent.size()) {
        for(int i = 0; i <= madLibsContent.size() - 1; i++){
            if (i == madLibsContent.size() - 1)
                contents += madLibsContent.get(i);
            else 
                contents += madLibsContent.get(i) + " " + Blanks.get(i).getBlankValue() + " ";
        }
    } else {
        for(int i = 0; i <= madLibsContent.size() - 1; i++){
            if (i == madLibsContent.size() - 1)
                contents += madLibsContent.get(i) + " " + Blanks.get(i).getBlankValue();
            else
                contents += madLibsContent.get(i) + " " + Blanks.get(i).getBlankValue() + " ";
        }
    }
    return contents;
}
```

Comment: First indent it properly. Then only you can proceed further.

Comment: Extracting methods is never a bad idea in such a huge block of code. Start with extracting three methods for the three if conditions and three methods for the three loops. Next would be creating a class for this getContents() thing.

Comment: @Dgrin91 The "also" may be misleading in that sentence. Just to clarify, it doesn't really belong on [so].

Answer (score 2):

Where you have the pattern of:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= madLibsContent.size() - 1; i++){
    if (i == madLibsContent.size() - 1)
        contents += madLibsContent.get(i) + " " + Blanks.get(i).getBlankValue();
    else
        contents += madLibsContent.get(i) + " " + Blanks.get(i).getBlankValue() + " ";
}
```

Replace it with:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= madLibsContent.size() - 1; i++){
    contents += madLibsContent.get(i) + " " + Blanks.get(i).getBlankValue();

    if (i < madLibsContent.size() - 1)     
        contents += " ";
}
```

Hint: Avoid copying and pasting code.

Comment: Yes, and manually typing the exact same line of code does not count as "avoiding copy and paste!"  :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
public String getContents(){
    if (Blanks.size() > madLibsContent.size()){
        for(int i = 0; i <= Blanks.size() - 1; i++){
            contents += Blanks.get(i).getBlankValue();
            if (i != (Blanks.size() - 1))
                contents += " " + madLibsContent.get(i) + " ";
        }
    }
    else if (Blanks.size() < madLibsContent.size()){
        for(int i = 0; i <= madLibsContent.size() - 1; i++){
            contents += madLibsContent.get(i);
            if (i != (madLibsContent.size() - 1))
                contents += " " + Blanks.get(i).getBlankValue() + " ";
        }
    }
    else{
        for(int i = 0; i <= madLibsContent.size() - 1; i++){
            contents += madLibsContent.get(i) + Blanks.get(i).getBlankValue();
            if (i != (madLibsContent.size() - 1))
                contents += " ";
        }
    }

    return contents;
}
```

---

First step was clearing out the redundancies: anything that occurs in all if-else statements should be moved outside of them.  Then it was just some logic fiddling to get the additional parts added.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you'd get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because when the one's bigger, you'd still try to access elements at those indices in the other one. The `i == Blanks.size()-1` should probably be `i >= madLibsContent.size()` (and similar changes for the other checks).

Assuming this is the case, below is a shorter, hopefully correct, version.

```
public String getContents()
{
    int max = Math.max(Blanks.size(), madLibsContent.size());
    for(int i = 0; i < max; i++)
    {
        if (i < Blanks.size())
        {
            contents += Blanks.get(i).getBlankValue();
            if (i < madLibsContent.size())
                contents += " ";
        }
        if (i < madLibsContent.size())
            contents += madLibsContent.get(i);
        if (i != max-1)
            contents += " ";
    }
    return contents;
}
```

Comment: Much cleaner than mine, but for some reason, I'm getting an error on the last two if statements. The i cannot be resolved for some reason.

Comment: @user2871716 The most likely cause is that there's a `}` that shouldn't be there, or there are too few `{`'s. The code as above compiles (as long as I define `contents`, `Blanks` and `madLibsContent` somewhere).